# How to deal with "Session resumption (caching)" warning?

Tags: tls

Can anyone explain the below "Session resumption (caching)" warning to me and how to deal with it? It's from an SSL Labs test.

[image: Screenshot of "Session resumption (caching)" warning.]

Comment: What's providing this warning? What's the context?

Comment: Tets on sslab test

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This isn't a security warning at all. It is more an indicator of a misconfiguration which is bad for performance but not relevant for security: The server issues session ID's for resumption but if the client tries to resume a session using the server provided ID it will not work. For reasons this might happen see [this discussion](https://discussions.qualys.com/thread/12407).

Comment: the link is dead...

Comment: @chicocvenancio: The link still works for me.

Comment: I feel like the statement "not relevant for security" is possibly questionable here. Considering availability, which is an integral part of information security (CIA-triangle). To my understanding of this issue, there is a (minor) risk considering the availability, that that the server cannot (at least, as easy) accept new TLS connections when overloaded when "session resumption (caching)" is not used or their assigned IDs are not accepted. What's your opinion on this @SteffenUllrich?

Comment: @BobOrtiz: With this argumentation practically every kind of misconfiguration, programming errors etc might be treated as on-topic since it might affect the availability or integrity. Where do you draw the line? I think if the OP would specifically ask about availability issues it would be on-topic since answers would focus on this security aspect. But a simple *"how to deal with ... warning"* is too unspecific to me here.